# cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer returns "unknown error"

Tags: opengl, interop, cuda

I am creating an OpenGL texture like this:

```
glGenTextures( 1, &boardTex );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, boardTex );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

I get a handle at `board` so I assume the texture's been successfully created. I want to share this texture with CUDA so I register and map the resource:

```
cudaGLSetGLDevice(0);
cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage( &boardImage, boardTex, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone );
cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &boardImage, 0 );
```

Then I try to get the mapped pointer like this:

```
float4* mappedPointer;
size_t mappedSize;
cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&mappedPointer, &mappedSize, boardImage );
```

Unfortunately this call returns an error and refuses to work. I made sure the texture wasn't bound in OpenGL context just in case. Still not working. `cudaGetErrorString` yields *"unknown error"* so I'm pretty stuck here. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Are `board` and `boardTex` the same value?

Comment: @harrism yes, my bad (board is local in some function.) Edited it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found this out myself:

`cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray (&array, resource, 0, 0);` returns a `cudaArray` to work with. I have yet to wrap my mind around how `cudaArray`s work (and I might end up using PBOs) but at least it's not crashing.

Edit:

From the CUDA Reference Guide entry for `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()`:

> If resource is not a buffer then it cannot be accessed via a pointer
>   and cudaErrorUnknown is returned.

From the CUDA Reference Guide entry for `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray()`:

> If resource is not a texture then it cannot be accessed via an array
>   and cudaErrorUnknown is returned.

In other words, use GetMappedPointer for mapped buffer objects.  Use GetMappedArray for mapped texture objects.